# Are there alternate definitions of the Weber number?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

The Weber number, *We*, is often defined as (density x velocity(2) x length)/interfacial tension.

It is also defined as (viscosity x sheer stress x length) / interfacial tension

In each case, the numerator parameters density/viscosity and velocity/sheer rate refer to the dispersed phase.

Are these equivalent, and how is this demonstrated?

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent. In the first case you are comparing inertial force to interfacial tension, and in the second case, viscous force to interfacial tension. Magnitude of each of these non-dimensional parameters tells you which terms in Navier-Stokes equation may be neglected to obtain a simplified equation.

Answer (score 1):

What is your source for the second definition, viscosity x shear stress x length / interfacial tension ? This is usually called the capillary number Ca, comparing viscous and interfacial effects, and is indeed different from the Weber number We.

You have We = Re Ca, where Re is the Reynolds number. Note that the Ohnesorge number is yet another one in the same 2 dimensional parameter space, Oh = $\sqrt{\text{We}} /\text{Re}$.

Comment: The second definition of We is given in Laurier L. Schramm, Emulsions, Foams, Suspensions & Aerosols (2nd ed) 2014, p92. The capillary number Nc given in this reference (p359) is:

Nc = viscosity x velocity / (interfacial tension x pore radius)

Comment: Seems they are in a specific context of multiphase flow in porous media? What is the length in their definition of We ? If they have 2 different reference lengths (pore radius and average pore length e.g.), then there will be two different numbers (although the aspect ratio would be a better choice), but I'd say it's very misleading and inappropriate to go against the commonly accepted definition of a number such as We.